# Heroku is giving 503 Unserviceable but works fine locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have hosted my node app on Heroku, 2 days back, hosted url was working fine but now, its giving 503 unservicable.

So, I ran this command to check the heroku logs  **heroku logs --tail** but didn't understand the issue.

Here are the logs:

```
     Started on port 48767
2021-01-05T15:34:49.765284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-05T15:34:51.254631+00:00 app[web.1]:  'error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.89.37.37", user "vnsxtpwrlssszb", database "de85b28qpdw9mb", SSL off
2021-01-05T15:35:21.190688+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/login" host=employee-tracker-b3.herokuapp.com request_id=33ee0c22-20fa-4d6c-a3cf-3a07aab83c96 fwd="49.36.228.98" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-05T15:35:21.194761+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/login - - ms - -
2021-01-05T15:35:27.892106+00:00 app[web.1]:  'error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.89.37.37", user "vnsxtpwrlssszb", database "de85b28qpdw9mb", SSL off
2021-01-05T15:35:57.882433+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/login" host=employee-tracker-b3.herokuapp.com request_id=7281dc7b-66ef-4101-a815-13a112765a1e fwd="49.36.228.98" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-05T15:35:57.885297+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/login - - ms - -
```